# Trying to include a button that opens and closes links for a moble site

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website which works well on test but when i go to mobile view my links get in the way of the rest of the page, so i want to know if there is a way to add a button that can open and close the links.

the navbar shortens when you scroll up and gets larger when you scroll up so far.

```
    <div id="navbar">
  <img src="../Assets/Banner3.png" alt="Banner" width="25%" height="60" id="logo">
  <div id="navbar-right">
    <a class="active" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="../htm/Contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="../htm/About.html">About</a>
    <a href="../htm/Social.html">Social</a>
    <a href="../htm/Website.html">Website</a>
    <a href="../htm/Computer.html">Computer</a>
    <a href="Phone">Phone</a>
</div>
  Contact us on  | Email us
  </div>
<script>
// When the user scrolls down 80px from the top of the document, resize the navbar's padding and the logo's font size
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "25px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "80px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "35px";
  }
}
</script>
```

any help will bee appreaciated.

Comment: You’ll need to implement a [Disclosure pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/disclosure/disclosure-navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `button` and do the following actions:

**On click event:**

- Add the css `display:none` property on the `div` if the `div` is visible.
- Remove the css `display:none` property from the `div` if it is present.

You will need to use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function to do this. I have added an example code using the above implementation here.

**Note: Also, another alternative approach is a collapsible `div`**.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "25px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "80px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "35px";
  }
}
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("navbar-right").style.display = document.getElementById("navbar-right").style.display == "none" ? "" : "none";
});
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <img src="../Assets/Banner3.png" alt="Banner" width="25%" height="60" id="logo">
  <div id="navbar-right">
    <a class="active" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="../htm/Contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="../htm/About.html">About</a>
    <a href="../htm/Social.html">Social</a>
    <a href="../htm/Website.html">Website</a>
    <a href="../htm/Computer.html">Computer</a>
    <a href="Phone">Phone</a>
  </div>
  Contact us on | Email us

  <button id="btn">Click to switch link view</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That’s a good start. To make it usable for people with disabilities, one would also need to control the `aria-expanded` attribute of the button, and it should be before the menu. See [Disclosure](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/). Instead of setting style, one could simply add/remove [the `hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden), as well.